# I want to render an rdlc report in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

i have an mvc project and i want to render a report in a view.

that what i have added in report.aspx

````
        void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!IsPostBack)
            {
                List<MVCReportViwer.Customer> customers = null;
                using (MVCReportViwer.MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MVCReportViwer.MyDatabaseEntities())
                {
                    customers = dc.Customers.OrderBy(a => a.ContactName).ToList();
                    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/RPTReports/rptCustomer.rdlc");
                    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                    ReportDataSource rdc = new ReportDataSource("MyDataset", customers);
                    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rdc);
                    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
                }
            }
        }

    </script>```

but there is an error
The view at '~/Views/Shared/ReportViwerASPX.aspx' must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage<TModel>
````

Comment: You have to show us ReportViwerASPX.aspx code if you need some help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.